# System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper string is being saved instead of file pathname

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This used to work fine, but now the code is not saving the pathname to the `SitePlan` and `SiteImage` fields. If I debug everything looks fine and `SitePlan` and `SiteImage` contain pathnames to the uploaded files (i.e. ~/UploadedFiles/20110210104108SiteImage77.jpg). But once save in the `SitePlan` and `SiteImage` fields is the string value "System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper".

Struggling with this since its saves fine and watching and debugging the value being saved is the pathname so no error and all appears to work, just the database has no path, just this string "System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper". Any comments greatly appreciated

Here is my controller code :

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult SiteLocationEdit(int id, FormCollection collection)
{
    SiteLocation siteLocation = this._siteRepository.GetSite(Convert.ToInt16(collection["SiteId"])).SiteLocation;           

    if (Request.Files.Count > 0 && Request.Files["SitePlan"].ContentLength > 0)
    {
        DeleteFile(siteLocation.SitePlan);
        siteLocation.SitePlan = SaveFile(Request.Files["SitePlan"], @"~/UploadedFiles", "SitePlan" + siteLocation.SiteId.ToString());
    }

    if (Request.Files.Count > 0 && Request.Files["SiteImage"].ContentLength > 0)
    {
        DeleteFile(siteLocation.SiteImage);
        siteLocation.SiteImage = SaveFile(Request.Files["SiteImage"], @"~/UploadedFiles", "SiteImage" + siteLocation.SiteId.ToString());
    }

    TryUpdateModel(siteLocation);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(siteLocation);  


    this._siteRepository.Save(User.Identity.Name);
    return RedirectToAction("SiteLocationDetails", new { id = siteLocation.SiteId });                                   
}
```

Here is my View containing a Partial View (shown later in this post)

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Lms.Model.SiteLocation>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    <%= Html.Encode(Model.Site.SiteDescription) %>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<%=Html.Script("~/Scripts/jquery.textarea-expander.js")%>

    <%= Html.ValidationSummary("Location Create was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.\n If you uploaded images during this update please upload again.")%>
    <% using (

        Html.BeginForm
        (
            "SiteLocationEdit",
            "Site",
            FormMethod.Post,
           // add an encoding type attribute
           // that is required for file upload
            new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }
        )

           )
       {%>
        <% Html.RenderPartial("SiteTabs", Model.Site); %>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
        <% Html.RenderPartial("SiteLocationForm", Model); %>


    <% } %>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            /* jQuery textarea resizer plugin usage */
            $(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery("textarea[class*=expand]").TextAreaExpander(); // initialize all expanding textareas, new code, john s 10/08/2010
            });
        </script>

</asp:Content>
```

**Here is the partial view :**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Lms.Model.SiteLocation>" %>
<fieldset>
    <div>
        <h3>
            <label id="Label2" style="text-align: left">
                <%= "Site Location: " + Html.Encode(Model.Site.SiteDescription) %></label>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="formFields">
        <ul>
            <%--This is used to identify the site object to update when the model is returned to the controller--%>
            <%= Html.Hidden("SiteId", Model.SiteId)%>
            <li>
                <label for="Latitude">
                    <strong>Latitude:</strong></label>
                <%= Html.TextBox("Latitude")%>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Latitude", "*")%>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="Longitude">
                    <strong>Longitude:</strong></label>
                <%= Html.TextBox("Longitude") %>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Longitude", "*") %>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="Location">
                    <strong>Location Address:</strong></label>
                <label><%= Html.TextArea("Location", Model.Location, new { @class = "expand50-200"}) %></label>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Location", "*") %>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="NearestPostcode">
                    <strong>Nearest Postcode:</strong></label>
                <%= Html.TextBox("NearestPostcode") %>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("NearestPostcode", "*") %>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="TimeFromOfficeToTurbine">
                    <strong>Office to Windfarm (Time):</strong></label>
                <%= Html.TextBox("TimeFromOfficeToTurbine") %>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("TimeFromOfficeToTurbine", "*") %>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="Directions">
                    <strong>Comments:</strong></label>
                <label><%= Html.TextArea("Directions", Model.Directions, new { @class = "expand50-200" })%> </label>
                <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Directions", "*") %>
            </li>

            <li>
            <h5><strong>For Image Uploads:</strong> Please use only JPG,JPEG or GIF formats.
            Image size should be appropriate for the webpage to display, approximately 500x375 (WidthxHeight)
            </h5>
            </li>

            <li>
                <label for="Site Plan">
                    <strong>Site Plan:</strong></label>
                <input id="SitePlan" name="SitePlan" type="file" />
            </li>

            <li>
                <label for="Site Image">
                    <strong>Site Image:</strong></label>
                <%--            <%//= Html.TextBox("SiteImage", Model.SiteImage)%>
            <%//= Html.ValidationMessage("SiteImage", "*") %>--%>
                <input id="SiteImage" name="SiteImage" type="file" />
            </li>


        </ul>
    </div>
</fieldset>
 <div class='demo'>
    <%=Html.ActionLink("< Back to List", "Index") %><input type="submit" value="Save" />
</div>
```

and here is the save file procedure in the controller code :

```
protected String SaveFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, String path, string name)
{
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        if (path == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("path cannot be null");
        }

        string fileType = file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.LastIndexOf("."), file.FileName.Length - file.FileName.LastIndexOf("."));

        String relpath = String.Format("{0}/{1}", path, PrefixFName(name + fileType));
        try
        {
            file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(relpath));
            return relpath;
        }
        catch (HttpException e)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Cannot save uploaded file", e);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is the SiteLocationCreate() THIS WORKS, just the EDIT that does not :

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult SiteLocationCreate(SiteLocation siteLocation, FormCollection collection)
{
    // TODO CF: Look into this line.  Is there a better way to do it?  I would think so.
    // It uses a hidden field in the object form
    Site site = this._siteRepository.GetSite(Convert.ToInt16(collection["SiteId"]));                        
    site.SiteLocation = siteLocation;

    if (Request.Files.Count > 0 && Request.Files["SitePlan"].ContentLength > 0)
    {
        DeleteFile(siteLocation.SitePlan);
        siteLocation.SitePlan = SaveFile(Request.Files["SitePlan"], @"~/UploadedFiles", "SitePlan" + siteLocation.SiteId.ToString());
    }

    if (Request.Files.Count > 0 && Request.Files["SiteImage"].ContentLength > 0)
    {
        DeleteFile(siteLocation.SiteImage);
        siteLocation.SiteImage = SaveFile(Request.Files["SiteImage"], @"~/UploadedFiles", "SiteImage" + siteLocation.SiteId.ToString());
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)              
        return View(siteLocation);                            

    this._siteRepository.Save(User.Identity.Name);
    return RedirectToAction("SiteLocationDetails", new { id = site.SiteId });                                   
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code for `SaveFile()`? I presume it's your own code.

Comment: Update complete, SaveFile() added, cheers

Comment: Spot on, thats it, going bananas here :-) Bizzarly the SiteLocationCreate() WORKS, posting it to post now

Comment: I'm not seeing anything obvious that would cause that behavior. For debugging purposes, have you tried setting the value of `siteLocation.SiteImage` before or after the `SaveFile()` call to see what's saved in the DB?

Comment: TryUpdateModel() after SaveFile(), as soon as code moves off TryUpdateModel() it has changed the 2 values

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25903/discussion-between-seanost-and-john)

Comment: Problem looks like TryUpdateModel() is the culprit then...

Answer (score 1):

Removed TryUpdateModel() line and its working. But had to then specify line by line for each of the field updates, i.e. siteLocation.Location = collection["Location"]; etc etc. Since TryUpdateModel has been taken out

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!